# How to combine two fields value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is output

[image: SQL Image]

but i want

[image: SQL image]

in this table `tb_user_connection` i get 4 row but i want only 3 so, if i get connection in 1 and 2 so not get repeated column.

i try below query and this is codeigniter project.

**my query:**

```
 SELECT * FROM `tb_user_connection` WHERE `connection_type` = 'a' AND (user_id = '1' OR connection_id='1')
```

Comment: Can you post expected output based on the above input? and also, explain why is it so?

Comment: Hello @GurwinderSingh i post this

Comment: The purpose was to explain why the output is like that. can you explain that?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh if user 1 is already connected with user 2 so this record give by sql as 3rd row so 4th row is waste and send me wrong figure so if user 1 is already connected with user 2 then again not get me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select *
from your_table
where user_id <= connection_id
union all
select *
from your_table t
where user_id > connection_id 
and not exists (
    select 1
    from your_table t1
    where t1.user_id = t.connection_id
    and t1.connection_id = t.user_id
) t1;
```

Comment: Thx bro but some fix by me but 99% by you.